# Why jeevatma gets detached from paramatma?

Tags: moksha, atma, paramatma

Jeevatma is like a droplet detached from paramatma, the ultimate omnipresent eternal soul.

By achieving moksha, jeevatma gets freed from reincarnation and gets merged in the paramatma.

But why the human soul gets detached from cosmic soul? Since moksha is attained that soul should never come back on earth. Our human existence is because we detached from para Brahma.
Why ?

Please enlighten.

Comment: Jeevatma is paramatma. It is just due to ignorance, it appears differently.